# how to install jpegoptim on php apache server

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, image-compression, jpegoptim

I am writing a php app to compress images on my server using *jpegoptim*.
Currently I have installed *jpegoptim* on my machine (Ubuntu14.04) and its working fine on the terminal.

But when I try to run the following code in a php file on my local machine nothing happens.

```
<? php
$path_to_jpg_file = "dump/f.jpg";
$path_to_jpg_file = escapeshellarg($path_to_jpg_file);
$compressed_jpg_content = shell_exec("jpegoptim --max=75 --strip-all --all-progressive - < ".escapeshellarg($path_to_jpg_file));
?>
```

I think that php is unable to find the *jpegoptim* command and thus unable to process the query, and hence I need to install *jpegoptim* on the server.

How do I install *jpegoptim* on my "server"?

NOTE: all the directories have 777 permission

Answer (score 1):

You can install it using this

```
apt-get install jpegoptim
```